# Failed to mount HFS drive using diskutil-mount, while /sbin/mount works fine

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

I have a disk image file (`.dmg`) with a single partition that points to an HFS+ formatted filesystem, which is observable via device file `/dev/diskNs1s1`. The record for the single image in the partition table is set to specific GUID that triggers `IOStorage` kernel module that suppose to run this filesystem.

Once I tried to mount this drive to selected folder using `/usr/sbin/diskutil mount ...` it appeared that the filesystem might be corrupted :

```
Volume on disk2s1s1 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option
If the volume is an APFS Volume, try the "diskutil apfs unlockVolume" verb
```

looking deeper into the unified logger printouts, I saw the following message :

```
mount blocked by dissenter PID=0 (unknown) status=0xf8da000c log=kDAReturnUnsupported
```

I also made sure that my image is well formatted using `fsck_hfs`

However, when I use `/sbin/mount -t hfs ...` I successfully managed to mount the filesystem.

Perhaps anyone can tell me what is the difference between those to supposedly similar commands under the hood ?

thanks